# function returns function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array  `this.colors = [RED, BLUE, GREEN]`, and sometimes I would like to pick one random color from this array. 
When I doing it by this way, the result is normal:

```
rand_color = this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colors.length)]
javascript: console.log(rand_color)
// => rgb(211, 65,  65)
```

But when I've wrapped it in the function:

```
this.pick_random_color = function() {
    return this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colors.length)];
}
```

that function doesn't return random value. Instead, I get this message in the log:

```
color = this.pick_random_color;
javascript: console.log(color); 
// => this.pick_random_color = function() {
// =>   return this.colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.colors.length)];
// => }
```

What's wrong with the function?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your use of `this` is obfuscating your code, it is totally unnecessary. DaveShaw is 100% right, you are assigning a null variable to `color` in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't you need parentheses after the call to `pick_random_color`?

```
color = this.pick_random_color();
```

What you appear to be doing is *assigning* `color` to the `pick_random_color` function, not executing it.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot parens.   You have to add () to this.pick_random_colors

Answer (score 2):

That is because `this.pick_random_color` is a reference to a function. You should execute this function by writing `this.pick_random_color()`.

But make sure the `this` keywords refers to the original object